# CustomControl using type Button as base not firing MouseLeftButtonUp event

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-5.0

I have created a simple custom ImageButton control based on the Button control. The idea is that I supply a mouse down image and a mouse up image and the images are swapped depending on the left mouse button action. The MouseLeftButtonDown event fires just fine, my image is updated, but the MouseLeftButtonUp event never fires.

Is there a reason for this, am I implementing it incorrectly?

Custom Control:

```
namespace Reader.Controls
{
    using System.IO;
    using System.Windows;
    using System.Windows.Controls;
    using System.Windows.Input;
    using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;

    [TemplatePart(Name = "PART_Image", Type = typeof(Image))]
    public class ImageButton : Button
    {
        public Image PartImage;

        public ImageButton()
        {
            this.DefaultStyleKey = typeof(ImageButton);
        }

        public override void OnApplyTemplate()
        {
            this.PartImage = this.GetTemplateChild("PART_Image") as Image;

            if (this.PartImage != null)
            {
                this.PartImage.MouseLeftButtonDown += this.PartImageOnMouseLeftButtonDown;
                this.PartImage.MouseLeftButtonUp += this.PartImageOnMouseLeftButtonUp;

                this.SetImageSource(OffImageSource);
            }
        }

        #region Dependency properties

        public byte[] OffImageSource
        {
            get
            {
                return (byte[])this.GetValue(OffImageProperty);
            }
            set
            {
                this.SetValue(OffImageProperty, value);
            }
        }

        public static DependencyProperty OffImageProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
            "OffImageSource", typeof(byte[]), typeof(ImageButton), new PropertyMetadata(null));

        public byte[] OnImageSource
        {
            get
            {
                return (byte[])this.GetValue(OnImageProperty);
            }
            set
            {
                this.SetValue(OnImageProperty, value);
            }
        }

        public static DependencyProperty OnImageProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
            "OnImageSource", typeof(byte[]), typeof(ImageButton), new PropertyMetadata(null));

        #endregion

        #region Button events

        private void PartImageOnMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs mouseButtonEventArgs)
        {
            if (this.PartImage != null)
            {
                this.SetImageSource(OnImageSource);
            }
        }

        private void PartImageOnMouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs mouseButtonEventArgs)
        {
            if (this.PartImage != null)
            {
                this.SetImageSource(OffImageSource);
            }
        }

        #endregion

        private void SetImageSource(byte[] imageSource)
        {
            using (var ms = new MemoryStream(imageSource, 0, imageSource.Length - 1))
            {
                var bi = new BitmapImage();
                bi.SetSource(ms);

                this.PartImage.Source = bi;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Default style template:

```
<Style TargetType="Controls:ImageButton">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Controls:ImageButton">
                <Image x:Name="PART_Image" />
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Usage:

```
<Controls:ImageButton x:Name="btnLangEn" Click="btnLangEn_Click" />
```

Usage code behind (ImageLibrary is a reference to resource file):

```
public LanguageSelection()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    btnLangEn.OffImageSource = ImageLibrary.LangEn_off;
    btnLangEn.OnImageSource = ImageLibrary.LangEn_on;
}

private void btnLangEn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // handle click event here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I sorted this by replacing the click handlers with overridden methods for OnMouseLeftButtonDown and OnMouseLeftButtonUp, like so:

```
    protected override void OnMouseLeftButtonDown(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnMouseLeftButtonDown(e);

        if (this.PartImage != null)
        {
            this.SetImageSource(OnImageSource);
        }
    }

    protected override void OnMouseLeftButtonUp(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnMouseLeftButtonUp(e);

        if (this.PartImage != null)
        {
            this.SetImageSource(OffImageSource);
        }
    }
```

This is recommended way to handle the event when in a derived class: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.control.onmouseleftbuttonup(v=vs.95).aspx